# CSS3 background image placement

Tags: css, background-image, centering

I am in the process of creating a simple placeholder page to announce  a new website.  The page consists of nothing other than

- a centered background logo image
- a "catch phrase" immediately below that image

I thought this would be easy - I place a positioned background image with its size specified and then place an absolutely positioned `h1` header to get the "catch phrase" right below the background image.

```css
*
{
 color:white;
 font-family:arial;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
}
body
{
 background-color:black;
 background-origin:border-box;
 background-image:url('https://unsplash.it/1064/800');
 background-size:auto 25%;
 background-position:center 37.5%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:100vh;
}
h1
{
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:62.5%;
 right:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3 is Cool!</h1>
```

This is working to the understanding that

- background-origin:border-box;
- `background-position:center 37.5%` with
- `background-size:auto 25%` would

yield an image with

1. The background image centered horizontally with its top left hand corner at 37% of its container height (set to `100vh`)
2. The  absolutely  positioned `h1`element is at (37.5 + 25)% from the top

For good measure I set `padding:0`and `margin:0`on everything.  However, the end result is not quite as expected - there is still way too much space between the bottom of the logo image and the top of the `h1`header.  Clearly, I am misunderstanding some aspect of background positioning and/or size here.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to put me on the right track

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using percent for background images, it doesn't work at all as one first think.

When you set background position using percent, that positions the image such that X% of the way across itself aligns with X% of the way across the element. This article at CSS Tricks shows it quite well: [percentage-background-position-works](https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/)

Use viewport height units `vh` instead

```css
*
{
 color:white;
 font-family:arial;
 margin:0 !important;
 padding:0 !important;
}
body
{
 background-color:black;
 background-origin:border-box;
 background-image:url('https://unsplash.it/1064/800');
 background-size:auto 25%;
 background-position:center 37.5vh;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:100vh;
}
h1
{
 text-align:center;
 position:absolute;
 top:62.5vh;
 right:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS3 is Cool!</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for the link - the way `background-position` uses % units is neat!  I wasn't aware of this

Comment: @DroidOS You're welcome, and I knew it did work like that but never found a good way to explain it...until I found that article some time ago :)

Comment: @DroidOS Bonus: If you use `vh` for the font size, it will scale along with image: https://jsfiddle.net/wtyu0saz/