# background-position for multiple images does not work as expected when using percentages

Tags: html, css

I found this code to render a chessboard-like.

```css
.chessboard {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: white;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black), 
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%, black);
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="chessboard"></div>
```

If I change background-position to `background-position: 0 0, 50% 50%;`, the second background-image does not appear as it was before, and the result is broken.

Can someone please explain this to me, and provide a solution for this?

I need to use percentage here instead of fixed-length because I need exactly four square per div, and the div size is not fixed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position: _“Percentages refer to the size of the background positioning area minus size of background image”_ A gradient doesn’t have an “image size”, so there is nothing available here that you could calculate a percentage of in the first place.

Comment: what type of output you need

Comment: @Bhargav: I need the same output as the original version (background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;), however, I need a dynamic style because I have divs in different sizes.

Comment: but in above  code you got the output

Comment: @Bhargav: The problem is, my current div is 100px by 100px, if I have another div in a different size, then I have to change 50px to a half width/height of the new div. The css style then is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If to use `background-image`, [***this post***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646244/css3-background-image-placement) shows how background position using percent works.

Here is a much simpler solution, using pseudo elements

[Fiddle demo, which scale using viewport units `vw`](https://jsfiddle.net/qwd6zzf0/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
.chessboard {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
  background-color: white;
}
.chessboard::before, .chessboard::after {
  content:  '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;  
  background-color: black;
}
.chessboard::after {
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

/* styling for this demo only */
.chessboard {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.chessboard.bigger {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="chessboard"></div>

<div class="chessboard bigger"></div>
```